# Installing HyperLedger on Win10 with WSL - DOCKER Blocker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to setup a HyperLedger Node for first time on Win10 with ASL/ Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The issue is getting DOCKER to run.  I understand **MOST** instructions on line are for **Ubuntu 18.x**  But I am stubborn and want to try **20.04 LTS**

The problem starts when I get to this point:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/prereqs.html

the command:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

returns this error:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down.

My theory is that Ubuntu 20 is culprit. Requesting course correction / Comments please.

---

### System:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
- Installed    Ram 16G
- Win 10 Pro
- OS: 19041.450
- Experience: Win Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.310

---

### Software:

**Docker:**
PS C:\Users\v> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community

1. Version:           19.03.12
2. API version:       1.40
3. Go version:        go1.13.10
4. Git commit:        48a66213fe
5. Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:43:18 2020
6. OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
7. Experimental:      false

---

**Server: Docker Engine - Community**
Engine:

1. Version:          19.03.12
2. API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
3. Go version:       go1.13.10
4. Git commit:       48a66213fe
5. Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:27 2020
6. OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
7. Experimental:     false
8. containerd:
9. Version:          v1.2.13
10. GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
11. runc:
12. Version:          1.0.0-rc10
13. GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
14. docker-init:
15. Version:          0.18.0

Comment: UPDATE...  I will do a full HOWTO when finished, but I just discovered that my version of Ubuntu 20.04 was WSL version 1...   Docker should be WSL Version 2, so this could be an issue as well.

Comment: WSL 1 uses dynamic translation to convert the linux calls to underlying windows calls. It's not a real linux system and so things aren't going to work as if you are on a real linux system. WSL 2 provides a more realistic environment with a VM and linux kernel, but I don't know if the instructions would work exactly as I still don't have WSL 2 myself to see how docker for windows presents itself in that environment. If you want true linux then use a hypervisor such as hyper-v, virtualbox or vmware and install a copy of ubuntu 20.04 into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo service docker start
```

Comment: $ sudo service docker start    [sudo] password for admin   docker: unrecognized service     I had tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried converting your distro to wsl 2?

you might have already enabled the linux subsystem for windows feature..

run the following command in an elevated powershell,

> wsl --set-version  2

substitute "Distro" with your specific version

for setting all future distributions to use WSL 2

> wsl --set-default-version 2

to verify the changes

> wsl --list --verbose